# Levene's Test in two different samples

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, variance, sample, levenes-test

How can I perform in R, a Levene's Test of two different samples to check homoscedasticity without being none of them a factor and not building new variables (what I really want to do is to compare variances of a variable in just a few levels of the factor, not all of them).

Comment: hey it should be do-able, but can you have some example dataset, and also what  you have tried so far

Comment: Is this a statistics question or an `R` question. Are you in need of the syntax to apply Levene tests to only a subset of your data or do you have statistical questions about applying Levene test to only part of your data?

Comment: just an R question @Bernhard

Comment: Just R questions are not on topic on CrossValidated. Sometimes software questions are closed very fast here, so don't be surprised if that happens to your next R question. Better put statistics questions here and software questions on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let x1 and x2 be the two different samples.

```
x1<- rnorm(100, 50, 16)
x2<- rnorm(100, 60, 18)

leveneTest(x~gr, data=rbind(data.frame(x=x1, gr='gr1'),
                             data.frame(x=x2, gr='gr2')), 
           center='mean')
```

Result

```
Levene's Test for Homogeneity of Variance (center = "mean")
       Df F value  Pr(>F)   
group   1  7.0547 0.00855 **
      198                   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

**Creating a function**

If you don't want to make any changes in the variable names in the code every time, you can create a new function as below:

```
library(car)

levtest<- function(x, y) {
  leveneTest(dv~gr, data=rbind(data.frame(dv=x, gr='gr1'),
                               data.frame(dv=y, gr='gr2')), center='mean')
}

levtest(x1, x2)
```

Result

```
Levene's Test for Homogeneity of Variance (center = "mean")
       Df F value  Pr(>F)   
group   1  7.0547 0.00855 **
      198                   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was looking for some alternative to leveneTest that avoid defining new variables as factors but your answes solves my problem perfectly.

Comment: @heyou You're welcome.